# getting a count and sum total for the latest date by category in real time

Tags: google-sheets

My original data looks like this:
[Original Data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uhCAFzhtdcgt-IPyRTmfxNxUNdx5ieBh)

I'm looking for a way for my query to return information ONLY for the latest date associated with each Test. For that date, I am looking to get the count number of customers and the $ Paid total. What's complicating my effort is the fact that multiple people could take the Test at a given date and across dates.

The ideal results should look like something like this:
[Ideal Results](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T484TTC7H8WeKH1wbFJSmb4Yj8vKxkWt/view?usp=sharing)

I am getting information submitted into this table via Google Forms in real-time hence row range will be dynamic & need a solution that can give me the info I am looking for at any given time.

Here is the one that came the closest for me (although still far off as it does not show the Count or the Total $):

`=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(QUERY({ROW(A2:A),SORT(A2:D)}, "SELECT MAX(Col1) WHERE Col3 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Col3 LABEL MAX(Col1)''",0),{ROW(A2:A), SORT(A2:D)},{2,3,4,5},0))`

Spreadsheet link for Original data and the results of the above query:
[Google Spreadsheet with Original Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eXX4JnN_tVVjATKUYW7ZYTU1i5OR7WwDhTZv86VTz-I/edit?usp=sharing)

I would really appreciate any insights or help from anybody.

Comment: Hi @user13537251, could you change permission on "Original data" document and give us a public read access ?

Comment: Apologies. It's done. The original as well as ideal results data also exist in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Have you considered having this done by a script rather than formulae?

Comment: I have not, @RafaGuillermo, although I would be open to it. I am not familiar with scripts and unaware of the pros/cons of doing that. May I ask what you think the advantages might be for doing so?

Comment: Scripts can be useful to use when formulae start to get long and complicated and therefore more difficult to compose. You can even write scripts which act as custom formulae so you can call them directly from your sheet like regular formulae (`=CUSTOMFUNCTION(A1)` for example).

Answer (score 0):

### Possible solution (based on your document)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tADqNS4YtdDrMjToCNy2auKB_eNuMdMEA4ahmYJi_3M/edit?usp=sharing

### Details:

- Lastest date for a test could be found using `FILTER` `MAX` functions
- Count for a test (at lastest date) could be found using `COUNTIFS`
- Sum for a test (at lastest date) could be found using `SUMIFS`

Comment: Thanks Tom! Your solution definitely works as long if I am copy/pasting the columns with the appropriate formulae. However, as my amended posting states (sorry for not being as clear originally), I am continuously getting rows of new data added to my table (titled "original data") that I need to accommodate. In other words new Tests/Customers/Payments are being recorded in real-time and I need to update the output to reflect this. I assume I need some sort of array equivalent to your suggestions but have been unsuccessful in my attempts to figure out. Any suggestions? Thank you!